# correct function output lead to garbage in printf

Tags: c, function, printf

I was practicing c programming on my own and I was asked to write an integer-to-string function. My code is as follows.

Everything was right until I tried to print out the function return in the main function. As "auto" showed me in Visual Studio, I had the right return value but it got messed up in the printf function. Any advice? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* itob(int n, char s[100], int b);
char reverse(char s[100],char i);
int main(void)
{
    int n,b,c=0;
    char* str;
    char s[100];
    ...

    str=itob(n,s,b);
    printf("%s",str);   //wrong
    main();
}

char* itob(int n, char s[100], int b)
{
int i=100,c,firstdig,a;
char str[100];
if(b==8)
    printf("0");
else if(b==16)
    printf("0x");

do
{
    c=n%b;
    if(c>9)
            s[i--]=c-10+'A';
        else 
            s[i--]=c+'0';
} while((n/=b)>0);
a=0;
c=i+1;
while(c!=101)
    {
        str[a]=s[c];
        a++;
        c++;
    }
str[a]='\0';    
return str;
```

}

Comment: Could you show the contents of `itob()` please? What does "messed up" involve? Do you see part of the string then garbage or is it all garbage? Are you NULL terminating your string?

Comment: Also, you appear to be recursively calling `main()`? Is that right?

Comment: Nope, calling `main()` recursively is an aberration, it is even forbidden in C++.

Comment: is "str" a local buffer to itob? if so, it resides on the stack and has therefore a very limited lifespan outside itob();

Comment: what if I don't call main before I return, is there another way that I  can recursively go through my function (therefore not restarting my program)?

Comment: I edited my code above and a new error message was prompted "Stack around the variable 's' was corrupted." and I don't know what it meant.

Comment: In `itob()`, the first assignment to `s` with `i` = 100.  As this is outside `s`, your _fortunately_ received the error message.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without the full `itob` function, at least the definition of `str`, for it may be referencing to a variable on the stack, instead of the heap, so when the function `itob()` returns, the reference to that memory is lost.

Comment: then what should I do to make sure that I have the correct reference to the heap? The 'itob()' function returned a pointer in my code so I passed it by reference, or didn't I?

Comment: You've passed `char s[100]`, which is right, but you've defined a `char str[100]` inside `itob()`. This is a local array, and that memory is out of reach outside `itob` function. You have two alternatives: either you define `char *str=malloc(100*sizeof(char))` and then return str or you could also pass another argument to `itob()`, for example a `char str_dest[100]` as reference, so then `itob()` can use this instead of defining its own destination string.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to retain the flavor of your coding style, below is a candidate solution.  You need to reverse the role of `s` and `str` in `itob`.  'str' is your working buffer and 's' is the destination passed in and returned.  Also initialize `i` to 99, not 100 to stay within `str`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* itob(int n, char s[100], int b);
char reverse(char s[100], char i);

int main(void) {
  int n;
  int b;
  //  int c = 0;
  char* str;
  char s[100];
  //    ...
  b = 8;
  n = 1234;
  str = itob(n, s, b);
  printf("%s\n", str);   //wrong
  b = 16;
  str = itob(n, s, b);
  printf("%s\n", str);   //wrong
  // main();
}


char* itob(int n, char s[100], int b)
{
int i=100-1,c/*,firstdig*/,a;
char str[100];
if(b==8)
    printf("0");
else if(b==16)
    printf("0x");

do
{
    c=n%b;
    if(c>9)
            str[i--]=c-10+'A';
        else
            str[i--]=c+'0';
} while((n/=b)>0);
a=0;
c=i+1;
while(c!=(101-1))
    {
        s[a]=str[c];
        a++;
        c++;
    }
s[a]='\0';
return s;
}
```